# How to not have my process dies out when my linux session goes time out

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I am running a very normal server written in python, here's how I start up my server

```
python main.py 2>&1 &
```

The process will simply get shutdown after some 20000 seconds after my linux session goes time out. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Using `nohup` as answered is an easy way, but for a more permanent solution you might want to look into setting up e.g. a systemd service for your application, so systemd will ensure it remains running at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start the process in detached mode by:

```
nohup python main.py 2>&1 1>/dev/null &
```